# How can I use NiFi to Invoke a HTTP and send a RESTful web Service to another machines with IP address?

Tags: web-services, wildfly, apache-nifi

Current setup, there are 2 computer machine

1. First machine (IP of 192.168.4.1)

- It contain the NiFi setup as show in the image below:

[NiFi setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti9Ai.jpg)

- Inside the NiFi setup, I get a file from a local directory and I invoke a HTTP POST to send over to the second machine which hit the Wildfly Restful Webservice endpoint. Below image show the configuration I have done inside the Invoke HTTP:

[Invoke HTTP configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VSwn.jpg)
(Note: the Remote URL: http://192.168.3.1:8081/JaxRS-Nifi/restapi/multipart/upload)

2. Second machine (IP of 192.168.3.1)

- It contain a Wildfly Restful Webservice which allow my first machine to hit the webservice endpoint.

Error that I am facing:
[NiFi Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTbbH.png)

I have a problem which the first machines doesn't send a HTTP POST over to the Second machines. I am currently looking for solutions on what are the different configurations should I do to make a NiFi HTTP over to hit the Restful Webservice endpoint?

Thanks. Appreciate if there is anyone who can help me.

Comment: Connection timeout looks like network problem (not nifi). From machine where you have nifi run  from console: `telnet 192.168.4.1 8081` and you should see the same error. Ask your network admins to setup routing between 2 machines.

Comment: @dagget do you have any example on how to setup routing between host computer and a VMware inside a host computer? thanks